# Apache ssl.conf and regex

Tags: python, regex, apache

I am trying to parse and rewrite Apache's ssl.conf file. I have entries like

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.2.165:443>
   ServerName layerv2t3.dev.ca.com
   DocumentRoot /etc/httpd/dispatcher_cache/layerv2t3

   SSLEngine on

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteOptions Inherit
 # Redirect root to '/admin/homeRedirect' to make sure the cached version is used
 # and to satisfy the Dispatcher Filter
 RewriteRule ^/$ /admin/homeRedirect [R=302,L]
 ProxyPass /admin http://localhost:8085/admin
 ProxyPassReverse /admin http://localhost:8085/admin
 ProxyPreserveHost on
 RewriteRule system/sling/cqform/defaultlogin.html /app/login.html [R,L]
 Header edit Location ^http: https:
    <Directory />
            <IfModule disp_apache2.c>
                    SetHandler dispatcher-handler
                    ModMimeUsePathInfo On
            </IfModule>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.0.2.165:443>
  ServerName layerv2t3.app.qa1.w2.saasqa.ca.com
  DocumentRoot /etc/httpd/dispatcher_cache/layerv2t3

  SSLEngine on

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteOptions Inherit
  # Redirect root to '/en_us/home.html' to make sure the cached version is used
  # and to satisfy the Dispatcher Filter
  RewriteRule ^/$ /site/en_us/home.html [R=302,L]
  RequestHeader edit Host (layerv2t3.app.qa1.w2.saasqa.ca.com) layerv2t3.dev.ca.com
  RequestHeader edit Origin (layerv2t3.app.qa1.w2.saasqa.ca.com) layerv2t3.dev.ca.com
  RequestHeader edit Referer (layerv2t3.app.qa1.w2.saasqa.ca.com) layerv2t3.dev.ca.com
  ProxyPass /admin http://localhost:8085/admin
  ProxyPassReverse /admin http://localhost:8085/admin
  ProxyPreserveHost on
  RewriteRule system/sling/cqform/defaultlogin.html /app/login.html [R,L]
  Header edit Location ^http: https:
  Header edit Location (layerv2t3.dev.ca.com) layerv2t3.app.qa1.w2.saasqa.ca.com
        <Directory />
                <IfModule disp_apache2.c>
                        SetHandler dispatcher-handler
                        ModMimeUsePathInfo On
                </IfModule>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.0.2.165:443>
  ServerName layerv2t5.app.qa1.w2.saasqa.ca.com
  DocumentRoot /etc/httpd/dispatcher_cache/layerv2t5

  SSLEngine on

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteOptions Inherit
  # Redirect root to '/en_us/home.html' to make sure the cached version is used
  # and to satisfy the Dispatcher Filter
  RewriteRule ^/$ /site/en_us/home.html [R=302,L]
  RequestHeader edit Host (layerv2t5.app.qa1.w2.saasqa.ca.com) layerv2t5.dev.ca.com
  RequestHeader edit Origin (layerv2t5.app.qa1.w2.saasqa.ca.com) layerv2t5.dev.ca.com
  RequestHeader edit Referer (layerv2t5.app.qa1.w2.saasqa.ca.com) layerv2t5.dev.ca.com
  ProxyPass /admin http://localhost:8085/admin
  ProxyPassReverse /admin http://localhost:8085/admin
  ProxyPreserveHost on
  RewriteRule system/sling/cqform/defaultlogin.html /app/login.html [R,L]
  Header edit Location ^http: https:
  Header edit Location (layerv2t5.dev.ca.com) layerv2t5.app.qa1.w2.saasqa.ca.com
        <Directory />
                <IfModule disp_apache2.c>
                        SetHandler dispatcher-handler
                        ModMimeUsePathInfo On
                </IfModule>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I want to be able to match 2 virtual host entries starting at "VirtualHost" and ending at "/VirtualHost" for ServerName layerv2t3. This includes the suffix dev.ca.com as well as app.qa1.w2.saasqa.ca.com but the regex I have is matching the closing VirtualHost all the way down below. I want to delete these entries and rewrite the file content, but that's the next step.

```
        app_host_entry = '\<VirtualHost \d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\:443\>' \
                         '\s+ServerName\s{tenant_id}.app*com' \
                         '?\</VirtualHost\>' \
                         .format(tenant_id=self.tenant_id)
```

The tenant_id in this case is layerv2t3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should match the All virtualhost block where there server name is `layerv2t3`

```
<VirtualHost.*\n\s+?ServerName.*?layerv2t3.*(\n.*?)+?<\/VirtualHost>
```

[Demo URL](https://regex101.com/r/J6VyEd/3)

Update:

Using `multiline` flag

```
<VirtualHost.*\s+?ServerName.*?layerv2t3.*(\s.*?)+?<\/VirtualHost>
```

[Demo URL](https://regex101.com/r/J6VyEd/5)

Matching SSL Port:

```
<VirtualHost\s\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:443>\s+?ServerName.*?layerv2t3.*(\s.*?)+?<\/VirtualHost>
```

[Demo URL](https://regex101.com/r/J6VyEd/7)

Comment: if you use multiline flag, you don't need \n ?

Comment: I need `\n` if i remove it the regex will stop on `ServerName` line but using `(\n.*?)+` make it complete the whole block until it matches `</VirtualHost>`. Also using `?` in `(\n.*?)` prevent the regex from matching the whole apache conf

Comment: Same goes for the `<VirtualHost.*\n` so `\n` for matching the break

Comment: @rexbelia I tried to add multiline flag and in this case \n wont be necessary!

Comment: Why didn't you get rid of \n in (\n.*?) if you're using multiline?

Comment: @rexbelia, check it now please !

Comment: I have added the IP and SSL port to regex too

Comment: Could you explain this part to me (assuming there's no multiline)
(\n.*?)+?

Comment: And how would you catch the entry starting from /layerv2t3.dev.ca.com
    farms
  {
  /layerv2t3.dev.ca.com
    {
    $include "dispatcher.headers.any"
    /virtualhosts
      {
      "layerv2t3.dev.ca.com"
      }
     $include "dispatcher.renders.any"
    /cache
      {
      /docroot "/etc/httpd/dispatcher_cache/layerv2t3"
      $include "dispatcher.cache.any"
      }
    }

Comment: `(\n.*?)` will match a newline and everything after it where `?` will make the match stop until it match a specific string. could you send me a gist with the last entry ? as i may write a regex that wont work in the original case you have. for example this should match the whole text in your comment `^\/layerv2t3\..*`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of (\n.*?) but about the +? following that, right before the close tag of </VirtualHost>. What does the +? do. This is slightly confusing since you already have the ? in (\n.*?). And how are the parenthesis helping?